# How to find frequency from a RRULE in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-calendar-api, icalendar, rrule

I am trying to find the frequency of a calendar event from a Google Calendar event.

I know that `dateutil.rrule.rrulestr` has a few methods to parse RRULE. But I have am not aware of a method that can return the frequency of the event.

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents). Creating recurring events is similar to [creating](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) a regular event with the [event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events)'s recurrence field set.

Here's a sample Python code using `RRULE`:

```
event = {
  'summary': 'Appointment',
  'location': 'Somewhere',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z',
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {
      'email': 'attendeeEmail',
      # Other attendee's data...
    },
    # ...
  ],
}

recurring_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

print recurring_event['id']
```

For more information, you may check this [article](https://labix.org/python-dateutil).